# ScintillaNET Control not displaying syntax coloring?

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, textbox, scintilla

I installed the ScintillaNET package in my project through the Nuget Package manager. Then I made the Scintilla textbox control appear in the tool box by adding the path of the installed Scintilla dll (by right click toolbox > choose items > browse). I mentioned my installation process because people online had lot of trouble getting this thing setup. Now to the real issue, when I drag the control on to a form, a text box appears but I can't get it to display syntax coloring even after setting the `Lexer` property to `cpp`. Doing this programmatically as shown in the documentation doesn't work either. Following is the code that I used(`scintilla` is the name of the scintilla control):

```
 // Configuring the default style with properties
 // we have common to every lexer style saves time.
scintilla.StyleResetDefault();
scintilla.Styles[Style.Default].Font = "Consolas";
scintilla.Styles[Style.Default].Size = 10;
scintilla.StyleClearAll();

// Configure the CPP (C#) lexer styles
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Default].ForeColor = Color.Silver;
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Comment].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 0); // Green
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.CommentLine].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 0); // Green
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.CommentLineDoc].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128); // Gray
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Number].ForeColor = Color.Olive;
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Word].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Word2].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.String].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(163, 21, 21); // Red
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Character].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(163, 21, 21); // Red
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Verbatim].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(163, 21, 21); //   Red
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.StringEol].BackColor = Color.Pink;
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Operator].ForeColor = Color.Purple;
scintilla.Styles[Style.Cpp.Preprocessor].ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
scintilla.Lexer = Lexer.Cpp;

// Set the keywords
scintilla.SetKeywords(0, "abstract as base break case catch checked continue   default delegate do else event explicit extern false finally fixed for foreach goto if implicit in interface internal is lock namespace new null object operator out override params private protected public readonly ref return sealed sizeof stackalloc switch this throw true try typeof unchecked unsafe using virtual while");
```

This code is directtly from the Scintilla [documentation](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Automatic-Syntax-Highlighting). And I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably obsolete and could be closed because in the meantime there were created Demo project on GitHub  https://github.com/robinrodricks/ScintillaNET.Demo which is covering this example and it is working perfectly.

See method `InitSyntaxColoring` in
https://github.com/robinrodricks/ScintillaNET.Demo/blob/master/ScintillaNET.Demo/MainForm.cs

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQf6X.png)